# PIVPN behind two private routers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ddns

I'm in the process of setting up my RPI to run PiVPN so that my mother can watch Geo-locked content from abroad. I'm following Adreass Spiess' #295 video. I'm having some trouble figuring out where to set up DDNS. I live in a student-house, we have a router on the ground floor and ethernet connections going to each room. I realised that I'd have to forward ports on both routers. What I have yet to figure out is where to install DDNS? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm fairly new to the world of computer networking. Please don't hesitate to ask for any missing information and thank you all for your understanding!
The RPI would be installed in my room and be connected to the '2nd'router.
My second router is currently set up as a "Wireless Router", I've understood from someone else's post that I'd benefit from setting her up as an
''Access Point'' instead.

Answer (score 1):

DDNS gives a name to an IP Address.

Given that you want to connect to the WAN Ip Address (the IP Address given by the internet provider) you need to setup the DDNS on the main router for the entire building.

If you were to setup DDNS on your 2nd local router, the following scenario would happen.

```
[Internet] 
  ⬇
[Main Router] Wan IP: 123.45.67.89, LAN range: 192.168.10.x
  ⬇
[second router] WAN IP: 192.168.10.1, LAN range: 192.168.0.x
  ⬇
[Raspberry PI] LAN IP: 192.168.0.79
```

The above is just an example.

Internet provides IP 123.45.67.89, so the main router will have its WAN addres the same. It creates its own network in the range 192.168.10.x.

Lets assume the secound router gets 192.168.10.51 assigned, and it sees the router as 192.168.10.1, then 192.168.10.1 would be the WAN IP address the router would see. Given that this is not accessible to the public having your DDNS setup on your router would be pointless.

Once DDNS is set on the main router, port forwarding needs to be adressed as follows:

The correct port would be opened from Main Router to IP of second router, secound router to IP of Raspberry PI.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your time. I have yet to figure out how to write in paragraphs using the forum. Pressing "Enter" causes me to post prematurely. Would you be so kind to make the same visualization if I were to put DDNS on the main router. Is it so that if I setup DDNS on the main router and set up the 2nd as an access point that the whole network shares a single IP subnet in other words, that they'd all share the same first three bytes? 192.168.137.X for example? Thanks again

Comment: You cannot post paragraphs in comments, only in your question and in answers. That said, a router ALWAYS creates a new network so sharing the first numbers is something you don't even want. You can hook up the main router to the second router through the LAN port instead of WAN port which disables the entire router part, but that also means that all the setup must be done through the main router and other devices join the same network, thus less secure in a shared house network.

Comment: @Amsterdamned96 DDNS is always configured on the WAN facing router _(DDNS provides a hostname to a dynamic [non-static] WAN IP)_, so you can't configure DDNS on a downstream router unless the downstream router receives a WAN IP. Configuring the router as a Smart/Managed Switch by not using the WAN port [LPChip's previous comment] _(or bridging the WAN and LAN ports into a vLAN)_ would put all downstream devices [second router and its devices] on the main router's subnet.